# Multiple 'or' for string comparaison

Tags: java

I'm creating a little program in which an user enters a command, and if its begins with some chars, it is not displayed.
Here's my code :

```
boolean cancel = false;
cancel = msg.startsWith("/?")||msg.startsWith("?/")||msg.startsWith("??")||msg.startsWith("::")|| and so on...
```

but I have plenty of those (actually 6). Is there a way to do this quicker ? Maybe with Lists or arrays, but I don't know how to use them to repeat the action multiple time.

Thanks !

Comment: does your tested values always have two caracters?

Comment: @tfosra Yes, there is only two chars

Comment: @AlexShesterov I'm trying it actually. Will see. Thanks

Comment: The caveat with the regular expression-based approach in the duplicate is that `?` is a metacharacter in regular expressions, so you'll need to escape it.

Comment: @AndyTurner Thanks dude. Wouldn't have escaped it...

Comment: @AndyTurner I'm using reply from the duplicate, but if i try to escape the `?` it gives me "Illegal escape character in string literal"

Comment: @cab13140 escape the escape: `\\?`.

Comment: My code now : `cancel = msg.startsWith("(??|?/|/?|::|:/|/:");`

Comment: @AndyTurner Nice, thanks. But I must escape only the `?`, or I must escape `:` and `/` too